# Finding the last unique identifier and checking for a number then comparing time to current time

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

@SOF

In my csv files as shown below, I'm trying to make a bit of code to cycle through and find the last unique class (a unique class is based on element 0 and element 1 merged together) in my example the last unique Class is:`Class02` and `CD1` which would equal: `Class02CD1`

It would then need to look at element 4 for the students in that uniqueclass (in this example there are only 2 students, if a number exists in any of them then it needs to then get the time from element 2 and compare it to the current time, if the current time is 30minuites or more after the time given it should print the word "Late"

#### CSV File

```
uniq1,uniq2,three,four,five,six
Class01,CD2,data,data,,data
Class01,CD2,data,data,22,data
Class01,CD2,data,data,,data
Class01,CD2,data,data,4,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,3,data
Class02,CD3,data,data,,data
DClass2,DE2,data,data,133,data
DClass2,DE2,data,data,24,data
Class02,CD1,13:01,data,,data
Class02,CD1,13:05,data,1,data
```

- Cycle through unique elements to find the last class.
- Check if a number exists in that unique class.
- If the number exists then it should get the time from element 2
- If the number exists and we've got a time then we should compare it to the current time.
- If the current time is 30 minuites or after the time in the last class then it should print "late" else do nothing.

Anyone know how to solve this, I'm completely lost and don't have a clue how to do this.

#### Prints

```
Class02CD1
Current: 2013-11-11 12:07:37.635000
Fetched: 2013-11-11 13:05:00
Calculated: 1382.61666667
late
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the **unique class** part?

Comment: It's just element 0 and element 1 merged on each line, so in my example there are 4 unique classes (groups of data)

Comment: And all unique classes are always grouped together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First iterate over the file and find out the class on the last line, and then iterate over the file again and now if the class name on a given line equals the stored class name then apply your conditions there and use `datetime` module to find out the time difference.

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import time
with open('abc1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        pass
    class_name = ''.join(line[:2]) #save the name on last line
    print class_name
    f.seek(0)           # Rest the file pointer t o the start of the file
    for line in reader:
        cls_name = ''.join(line[:2])
        if cls_name == class_name:
            if line[-2]:
                current_dtime = datetime.now()
                fetched_time = datetime.strptime(line[2], '%H:%M')
                fetched_time = datetime(year=current_dtime.year,
                                        month = current_dtime.month,
                                        day = current_dtime.day,
                                        hour = fetched_time.hour,
                                        minute = fetched_time.minute
                                        )
                if ((current_dtime - fetched_time).seconds/ 60.0) > 30.0:
                    print "late"
```

Comment: Oh wow, that looks lovely the way you got the class name I would never of thought of. I am however having an issue with it returning late even tho it's not late... See my edit for the prints

Comment: @Hyflex try using this condition: `if (current_dtime > fetched_time) and ((current_dtime - fetched_time).seconds/ 60.0) > 30.0:`

Comment: That worked perfectly, why was the original way not?

Comment: @Hyflex `((current_dtime - fetched_time).seconds)` returns the number of seconds passed between the two times, it is always going to be positive even if `fetched_time > current_dtime`, so added an `AND` condition to check whether the `current_dtime` is greater than `fetched_time` or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer up to the time comparison part at the end.

```
import csv

dict = {}
key = False
with open('test.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile,)
    first = False
    for row in reader:
        if first:
            first = True
            continue
        key = row[0]+row[1]
        if key in dict:
            dict[key].append(row)
        else: 
            dict[key] = [row]
    print dict

if(key):
    for row in dict[key]:
        # do time comparison
        pass
```

Comment: Some brief explanation of the algorithm would be nice IMhO.

Comment: @barry Looks good, Although you do know of the enumerate function right?